# C# MultiThreading Start and stop in FOR loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops

Hello guys Im looking for solution to stop specified thread for example

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   Thread th = new Thread(doWork(i));
}
```

and when all 10 threads started I wanna stop for example thread i = 5;
is it even possible? to do it this way?

Comment: Create a CancellationTokenSource and pass the CancellationToken to the thread.

Comment: Show your `doWork` method.

Comment: Please describe your actual use case. Threads need be cooperatively managed, i.e. the code that is running must check something periodically to cancel/complete/pause etc. Also, Tasks or Parallel.for is probably the way to go rather than using raw threads.

Comment: @SomeBody I give example as my doWork method is very long and u wont understand what it does kinda as its very messy

Answer (score -1):

You can check this code:

class Program
{

```
static int workingCounter = 0;
static int workingLimit = 10;
static int processedCounter = 0;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Temp");
    int checkCount = files.Length;
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        //wait for free limit...
        while (workingCounter >= workingLimit)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        workingCounter += 1;
        ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(ProcessFile);
        Thread th = new Thread(pts);
        th.Start(file);
    }
    //wait for all threads to complete...
    while (processedCounter< checkCount)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Work completed!");
}

static void ProcessFile(object file)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " recieved: " + file + " thread count is: " + workingCounter.ToString());
        //make some sleep for demo...
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle your exception...
        string exMsg = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref workingCounter);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref processedCounter);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This does however not show how to stop threads

Comment: I would not say that this is a great example on how to do multithreaded processing. I do not think looping over a sleep that way is the best way to check that all threads are finished. I'm not even sure it is safe.

Comment: Even if this did answer the question, and it doesn't, this is a bad way of handling this.